# Why should "ordinary string formatting" be used for table/field names in psycopg queries?

Tags: sql, psycopg2

From the documentation on properly passing SQL parameters to psycopg2:

"Only variable values should be bound via this method: it shouldn’t be used to set table or field names. For these elements, ordinary string formatting should be used before running execute()."

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Why is this? Why would setting a field name not have the same SQL injection problems as setting values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't usually receive names of your tables or fields from users, you specify them in your code yourself. If you generate your request based on values got from user input, than yes, you should do some kind of escaping to avoid SQL injections.